# Export nested object to CSV

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper library to export data to CSV. I'm facing a difficulty on creating a map for the nested list object.

```
public class Level1
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Level2 Level2 { get; set; }
}

public class Level2
{
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public List<Level3> Level3 { get; set; }
}
public class Level3
{
    public int Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

As an output of the csv what  want to have is:

```
Prop1,Prop2,Prop3,Prop4,Level3
  1  ,test ,2    , LL, , <list as ; separated>
```

Can anyone help me out on creating the map using CsvHelper library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nested list, you could use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) to concatenate `prop5`, like the following code :

```
List<Level1> levels = new List<Level1>();
var result = levels.Select(x => new
{
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2,
    Prop3 = x.Level2.Prop3,
    Prop4 = x.Level2.Prop4,
    Level3 = string.Join(";", x.Level2.Level3.Select(y => y.Prop5))
}).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.